# Is there a tool I could use to scan through all possible code paths and submethods of a C# method and return occurrences of a specific string?

Tags: c#, code-analysis

Suppose I have the following code

```
public class RandomClass
{
    public void MethodOne(){
        MethodTwo();
        Console.WriteLine("Include Scarab");
    }

    public void MethodTwo(){
        Console.WriteLine("Scarab");
    }
}
```

Is there a tool that I can use that will analyze a method (in this case MethodOne) and return all lines that contain a string (in this case Scarab)? In this case the tool would return `Console.WriteLine("Include Scarab");` and `Console.WriteLine("Scarab");`.

This would span across methods that are called through different files and projects within a solution.

Comment: Could you please explain what problem you solve by not just using a global search on that specific string?

Comment: In the solution, there is a class with an enum of various errors defined. As a result, I would have to continually check to see all references of each error to see which HTTP route generates the error. Using the tool, I would be able to pretty much see what errors are called by each method through the business and data layers.